# Express detect if request came from a subdomain?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using npm subdomain, and to keep routing clean I would like to do something like.

```
router.get('/login_success',function(req,res) {

  if(req.subdomain) {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } 

});
```

In the above, if the user logs in the app via sub-domain, I redirect to the sub-domain root which renders a profile.

If the user logs in via the non sub-domain route, it's using ajax to render a view so I need to send a 200 status saying the user is valid.

I figured this is much more clean that having two separate callback routes for each.

So my question, is there a way to detect if the req came from a sub-domain or regular domain.

I know there is `req.headers.origin` but I am wondering if there is a more relative way of doing it, so when going back and forth between local and production I don't have to change it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `req.subdomains`, this will give you a list of subdomains used in the url. [**Here's**](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.subdomains) where I got the information from.

Comment: Wow I was close, I tried `req.subdomain` just to test it and got nothing. I also inspected the `req` object and couldnt find anything. But it worked, awesome man!

Comment: No problem, any more problems always refer to the docs, http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html